# vb.net web service active connection test

Tags: vb.net, web-services

What is the best way to check if a web service is up and active?

I realize there are many different factors to this, but I would like to do something simple before sending data, like at the moment the proxy is constructed to see if the service is able to be connected. I am coding in vb.net.

Is there even a best practice for this type of comm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out if a Web service is running or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170380/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-web-service-is-running-or-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the simplest way is to "ping" your web service, querying a simple method like current version.

Example (PowerShell) to log the current version (method Version()) to the Application Event Log

```
$ApplicationEventLog = New-Object System.Diagnostics.EventLog('Application')
$ApplicationEventLog.Source = "My Webservice Ping"

try
{
    $wsproxy = New-WebserviceProxy -uri "http://mywebservice:7777/MyService.svc?wsdl"
    $message = "My Webservice Version is {0}" -f $wsproxy.Version()
}
catch [System.Exception]
{
    $ApplicationEventLog.WriteEntry($_.Exception.ToString(), [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Error)
}

$ApplicationEventLog.WriteEntry($message,[System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Information)
```